# ReSharper css-error on combined media-queries

Tags: html, css, resharper

I have taken over a existing web-project and `ReSharper` is throwing some css-errors.

At this line:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px), @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 1024px)
```

`ReSharper` throws

> { expected

When removing `, @media only screen`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 1024px)
```

the error goes away.

Now I'm wondering if this is still valid and has the same meaning as before or is this completely different code?
If different, how should it be changed to have no errors but still same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one"  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 1024px) " is proper one . and will produce desired results.